# How to set dynamic pixel offsets for infoboxes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with multiple markers of basically 2 types. One is a larger, wide marker, and the other is a lot smaller, square marker. Both types need to have an infobox that appears when clicked. Due to the different shapes and sizes of the markers, I'd very much like the infobox windows to be anchored at different positions based on which marker is being clicked. Of course I found the pixelOffset property for the infobox options, but I seem unable to set this dynamically based on the marker my loop is passing over. Basically I loop over an array of markerdata, build the marker (via the 'new google.maps.marker()' thing), then proceed to add an event listener for clicks on the marker which calls the function to open an infobox.

So my question is, after looking at the below code, how can I set the pixelOffset of the infobox dynamically?
What I've tried below clearly doesn't do the trick! The alert I dumped in there does actually show the correct settings when I load the page!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var LocationData = [
    [29.966270,-95.682491, "bhi", "Company Houston", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1"],
    [34.936190, -88.655899, "motors", "ConocoPhilips", "testfield #1", "rig #1", "HT102313MTR", "Eagle Ford", "v", "m", "0"],
    [32.133333, -102.3167, "type1", "Halliburton", "Test Field #2", "H&P #48", "HT070313RSS", "Bakken", "h", "m", "1"],
    [47.4667, -100.9333, "type2", "BP", "Test Field #3", "Ensco #318", "CC111512GWD", "Marcellus", "s", "", "2"],
    [41.5700, -117.7839, "type3", "Drake Directional", "Test Field #4", "H&P #143", "PE010214MWD", "Utica", "j", "f", "3"],
    [40.4667, -76.9333, "type4", "Shell", "testfield #5", "Ensco #23", "HT121213GYRO", "Barnett", "h", "m", "4"],

];

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();  
});

var side_bar_html = '';
var gmarkers = [];
var htmls = [];

var myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(29.966270, -95.682491);
var mapOptions = {
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
};

boxText = document.createElement("div");

function iconSizeFunction(usedIcon) {
    switch(usedIcon)
    {
    case 'bhi':
        var iconSizew_or = '68';
        var iconSizeh_or = '72';
        var iconSizew = '34';
        var iconSizeh = '36';
        var iconOriginw = '17';
        var iconOriginh = '28';
        var infoboxOffsetw = '200';
        var infoboxOffseth = '10';
        return [iconSizew_or, iconSizeh_or, iconSizew, iconSizeh, iconOriginw, iconOriginh, infoboxOffsetw, infoboxOffseth];
        break;
    default:
        var iconSizew_or = '264';
        var iconSizeh_or = '70';
        var iconSizew = '132';
        var iconSizeh = '35';
        var iconOriginw = '17';
        var iconOriginh = '-5';
        var infoboxOffsetw = '150';
        var infoboxOffseth = '200';
        return [iconSizew_or, iconSizeh_or, iconSizew, iconSizeh, iconOriginw, iconOriginh, infoboxOffsetw, infoboxOffseth];
        break;
    }
}

function initMap()
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var iconUsed;

    for (var i in LocationData)
    {
        var p = LocationData[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
        var iconUsed = p[2];
        var iconSizes = iconSizeFunction(p[2]);
        var infoBoxPosition = new google.maps.Size(iconSizes[6], iconSizes[7]);

        var jobStatus = p[10];

        switch(jobStatus)
        {
        case '0':
            jobStatus = 'off';
            break;
        case '1':
            jobStatus = 'on';
            break;
        case '2':
            jobStatus = 'up';
            break;
        case '3':
            jobStatus = 'unknown';
            break;
        case '4':
            jobStatus = 'new';
            break;
        }

        bounds.extend(latlng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: {
                url: '/images/mapicons/' + iconUsed + '_' + jobStatus + '.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(iconSizes[0], iconSizes[1]),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(iconSizes[4], iconSizes[5]),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(iconSizes[2], iconSizes[3])
            },
            shape: {
                coord: [0, 0, iconSizes[2], iconSizes[3]],
                type: 'rect'
            },
            optimized: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            content: '<div class="boxOptionsHeader"><h2>' + p[3] + '</h2></div><div class="boxOptionsExtra">' + p[4] + '<br /><a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=' + p[0] + ',' + p[1] + '">Directions to here</a></div>'
        });

        var i = gmarkers.length;
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        markerLength = gmarkers.length-1;
        side_bar_html += '- <a href="javascript:sidebarclick(' + markerLength + ')">' + p[3] + '<\/a><br \/>';


        alert(infoBoxPosition);
        var boxOptions = {
            content: boxText,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            alignBottom: true,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: infoBoxPosition,
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: {
                width: "240px"
            },
            closeBoxMargin: "0px 0px 0px -40px",
            closeBoxURL: "/images/mapicons/close_info.png",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            visible: true,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false,
            boxClass: 'boxOptions'
        };

        //console.log(marker.content);
        var ib = new InfoBox(boxOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            boxText.innerHTML = this.content;
            ib.open(map, this);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            ib.close();
        });

        function setZoomWhenMarkerClicked() {
            var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
            if (currentZoom < 7) {
                map.setZoom(7);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function sidebarclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

</script>
```

And here's the CSS for the box.

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #FFF; }
#map-canvas { height: 100%;}

.infobox-wrapper {
    display:none;
}

.boxOptions {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #E1002B;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    color:#5B6770;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-shadow:0 -1px #FFF;
    z-index: 20;
}

.boxOptionsHeader {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

.boxOptionsExtra {
    margin-top: -12px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}

.boxOptions:after, .boxOptions:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 15px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.boxOptions:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.boxOptions:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #E1002B;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide links to the icons?

Comment: and the css for the box, or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Changed the whole thing, live preview of what I'm trying to do can be found [here](http://michieloosterling.com/maptest/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of the infoboxes inside the loop is redundant, all the markers will use the same infobox(the last one that will be created. Note that you overwrite the `ib`-variable on each iteration). Create a single `InfoBox`-instance outside of the loop with default-options.

**How to apply the dynamic pixelOffset:**

Store it as a property of the markers, e.g.:

```
ibOffset :new google.maps.Size(iconSizes[6], iconSizes[7])
```

in the `click`-listener set the `pixelOffset`-option of `ib`:

```
ib.setOptions({'pixelOffset':this.ibOffset});
```

**But the most important thing:**

`google.maps.Size()` expects the arguments to be of type **Number**, but you provide **Strings**.

Remove the quotes around the values of `infoboxOffsetw` and `infoboxOffseth`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed everything you mentioned (infobox creation outside of the loop, changed the arguments from type string to type number, etc) but I still seem to be unable to dynamically position the infoboxes themselves. The only thing being defined/set within the loop at the moment is the content and the pixel offset in the manner you suggest above. Every box still has the exact same position as the other ones, even though an alert() inside the loop confirms the various offsets set. Any ideas?

Comment: Changed the whole thing, live preview of what I'm trying to do can be found [here](http://michieloosterling.com/maptest/).

Comment: I've been messing with it for quite some time now, and still can't get the various offsets to work the way it should. No matter what I try, the stupid infoboxes still open at (what seems to be) the last pixelOffset set for a particular infobox. What am I still doing wrong here?

Comment: Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/sLYeQ/  The modifications are in line 139 and 155 of the Javascript-frame.

Comment: Good stuff. Works like I expected it too! Thanks much, good sir. Answer accepted!