# Infobox cant postion exactly above the marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have used customized infobox here and cant position infobox exactly above the marker,

Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uGnQb/6/

```
var myMapOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: secheltLoc,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,    
};
```

Pleae click on the first marker, you can see that in infobox will position exactly above the marker, but infobox for the second marker is not positioning exactly above the marker.

Please help me on this?

Comment: Both infoboxes appear below the marker for me in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGnQb/6/)

Answer (score 0):

When creating your `InfoBox` object set and adjust `pixelOffset` and `alignBottom` to `true`:

```
var htmlInfoWindow = new InfoBox({
      content: "",
      closeBoxURL: "",
      position: marker.getPosition(),
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, -250),
      alignBottom: true
});
```

Please, note the height and width must be the same for all infoboxes

Answer (score -1):

Your both of the infoBoxes are opening below the marker, that is because the infoboxes are set with some position offset values which are to be adjusted while declaring them. The pixelOffset is set to (-140, 0).
refer to this [infobox documentation](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Comment: @gaurraw: Please refer this link "http://jsfiddle.net/uGnQb/48/, now you can see that first infobox is exatly above the marker and second will not? please advice?

Comment: both are at same offset position, its just that your second infobox has height greater than the first, so you have to declare the second infobox separately with its appropriate offset values or you can fix the height same for all infobox(advised). the height increases downwards in case of infoboxes.

Comment: @gaurraw: Thanks, but instead of using seperate infobox with appropriate values, is it possible to do it dynamically?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262380/how-to-set-dynamic-pixel-offsets-for-infoboxes

Comment: Maybe you want to use [infobubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html) rather than [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html)